# How to show rating using row chart in dc js

Tags: jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

How can i show rating using dc js.I need to show all rows from 0 to 5. My json format is

```
[
    {
        "id": "32203",
        "Rating": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "32224",
        "Rating": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "32248",
        "Rating": "4"
    },
    {
       "id": "32286",
        "Rating": "5"
    },
    {
        "id": "32249",
        "Rating": "4"
    },
    {
        "id": "32255",
        "Rating": "1"
    }
]
```

I took dimension as 'rating' and simply grouped it. Here as you can see there is no `id` with rating `2 and 3`.Automatically on loading a row chart with rating `0,1,4,5` will appear. I need to show blank row for `2 and 3` ratings in this row chart. Can anyone tell how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the row chart does not use a scale for the y axis I would create a "fake group" and add the missing rows.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted